# How to run an python app on subdomain

Tags: python, django, subdomain

Hello guys my questions is little stupid but i'm raining in a huge problem.

I have a django project at http://hgisocial.com
on the same server i want to use a PHP project who should be on subdomain (http://builder.hgisocial.com),
we have given correct DNS record in domain setting but don’t know how to redirect our subdomain to that specific folder
we have builder folder at /usr/home/builder

If any one helps me in short would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Is it the Python app or the PHP one you want to run on the subdomain?

Comment: Also, what webserver?

Comment: Its PHP app and i'm using FreeBSD 10 x64 server

Comment: Check the appropriate stanzas for the web server you are using

Comment: What **web**server are you running? Apache, nginx, etc.